# Add pattern to every row in alternate way in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) which has a column (c1) which looks like this:

```
c1

AA
AA
BB
BB
CC
CC
DD
DD
```

I would like to have such an output

```
c1

AA_1
AA_2
BB_1
BB_2
CC_1
CC_2
DD_1
DD_2
```

I have a code right now to add a specific pattern to all the rows:

```
strsplit(paste(df$c1, collapse='_1 '), ' ')[[1]]
```

However, how can I add the pattern "_1" to all the odd rows and the pattern "_2" to all the even rows?

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: Does `paste0(df$c1, c("_1","_2"))` work for you?

Comment: or `df$c2 = paste(df$c1, 1:2, sep ='_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `dplyr` solution.

```
df %>% mutate(c2 = paste(c1, 1:2, sep = "_"))

  c1   c2
1 AA AA_1
2 AA AA_2
3 BB BB_1
4 BB BB_2
5 CC CC_1
6 CC CC_2
```

---

Here is base way @RonakShah provide:

```
with(df, paste(c1, 1:2, sep = "_"))
# [1] "AA_1" "AA_2" "BB_1" "BB_2" "CC_1" "CC_2"
```

---

```
# data
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df$ID=c(1:nrow(df))
df$New_C1<-ifelse(df$ID%%2!=0,paste0(df$c1,"_1"),paste0(df$c1,"_2"))
df
```

Or if you need to overwrite, then:

```
df$ID=c(1:nrow(df))
df$c1<-ifelse(df$ID%%2!=0,paste0(df$c1,"_1"),paste0(df$c1,"_2"))
df$ID<-NULL
```

Result:

```
    c1
1 AA_1
2 AA_2
3 BB_1
4 BB_2
5 CC_1
6 CC_2
7 DD_1
8 DD_2
```

Answer (score 1):

to be on the safe side and handle cases where there not be an even number of entries, you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

# define data; has some 'odd' cases
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD", "DD", "EE"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# split the data by 'c1' and then add a suffix based on the number of entries
result <- df %>%
  group_by(c1) %>%
  mutate(new_C1 = paste0(c1, "_", seq(n())))

> result
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   c1 [5]
   c1    new_C1
   <chr> <chr> 
 1 AA    AA_1  
 2 AA    AA_2  
 3 BB    BB_1  
 4 BB    BB_2  
 5 CC    CC_1  
 6 CC    CC_2  
 7 DD    DD_1  
 8 DD    DD_2  
 9 DD    DD_3  
10 EE    EE_1
```